# How to create a custom keyboard layout for Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, keyboard-layout

I want to create a custom keyboard layout for Windows 8, as the standard Persian keyboard layout has many problems and many keys have been replaced.

Is there a way or any software which I can use to create a custom keyboard layout?

Comment: Have you tried Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator 1.4? Win8 isn't officially supported, but there are numerous reports that it works fine.

Comment: Thanks it seems that I have to check it. I will report the results here :)

Comment: @RezaAmeri does it work fine?

Comment: @Josem it is like hundred years ago and I can not remember, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [AutoHotKey](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDMQFjAA&url=http://www.autohotkey.com/&ei=2WlQUaPcOcOHhQf_zYHICg&usg=AFQjCNFPilXcl_JZc0P02lpflIlG3G-Q-w&bvm=bv.44158598,d.ZG4). It allows you to map your keyboard.

> AutoHotkey is a free, open-source utility for Windows. With it, you
>   can:
>
> - Automate almost anything by sending keystrokes and mouse clicks. You can write a mouse or keyboard macro by hand or use the macro
>     recorder.
> - Create hotkeys for keyboard, joystick, and mouse. Virtually any key, button, or combination can become a hotkey.